# Localize Label for property entity

Tags: codefluent

I'm using codefluent entities and I was wondering if is possible set a localized label for the properties of a entity example I have a Test entity with a name and description field I want to set custom labels for example in english is name an description but in spanish I want to set nombre and descripción I searched in the documentation but I didn't find the option

Answer (score 0):

CodeFluent Entities provides two ways to localized properties:

## Static Resources

CodeFluent Entities handles [static localization with the message concept](http://www.softfluent.com/documentation/BOM_LOC_StaticResources.html). Static resources refer to all those UI messages that will never change throughout your application's life-time: labels, error messages, information messages, titles, button texts, tool tips, etc.

```
<cf:property name="Description">
  <cf:message cultureName="en-US" value="Description EN"/>
  <cf:message cultureName="fr-FR" value="Description FR"/>
</cf:property>
```

- https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/Messages_Section.html
- https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/BOM_LOC_StaticResources.html

## Dynamic resources

CodeFluent Entities also handles dynamic localization out of the box. Dynamic resources refer to localized data created at runtime. For instance a web shop could have an international catalog in several languages, and this catalog should be displayed in a specific language depending on the users' language (i.e. culture in .Net). Administrators add, remove or modify items from this catalog during the application's life-time. Thus, administrators of the catalog will need to create catalog items with labels in several languages in order to support internationalization.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- http://www.softfluent.com/documentation/BOM_LOC_DynamicResources.html
- https://blog.codefluententities.com/2014/09/15/localize-dynamic-resources-using-aspect/